# Are there independent studies on the efficacy of vaccines?

Tags: vaccination, epidemiology, reference-request

Is there a collection, meta analysis or review of significant, independent studies that prove the efficacy of vaccinations? I am in discussion with a anti-vaccinationist who claims that the efficacy has not been proven. She does not trust in studies commissioned by vaccine manufacturers because she believes that they are in a conflict of interest. I have no expertise in this field, but I would like to show her that she is wrong and that the efficacy (as well as the effectiveness) of vaccinations is sufficiently proven. Can you recommend good literature?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I recommend adding ”reference-request” and 'epidemiology' tag. 　
There are various vaccines. Which vaccine do you want to know?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question. The conversation with the anti-vaxxer was mainly about vaccinations for babies (diphtheria, polio, whooping cough, etc.). But since she doubts the efficacy in general, it is almost irrelevant which vaccine is discussed...

Comment: Good luck. I have yet to encounter an anti-vaxxer whose mind can be changed with any amount of data. If they were amenable to data, they wouldn't be anti-vaxxers in the first place.

Comment: ＠ Carey Gregory　I am not a medical expert. However, I am statistically literate. I agree that anti-vaxxers tend to cling to their self-righteous beliefs. However, I also think that regulatory science tends to be closer to pseudoscience.　There is a bad culture in regulatory science, like p-value universalism. When I saw the Cochrane review of Tamiflu, I was ashamed of my blind faith in the regulatory authorities.

Answer (score 2):

How about the [Cochrane Collaboration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochrane_(organisation))?

For example,

- [MMR vaccines](https://www.cochrane.org/news/cochrane-review-confirms-effectiveness-mmr-vaccines)
- [Vaccines for the common cold](https://www.cochranelibrary.com/cdsr/doi/10.1002/14651858.CD002190.pub5/full/ja?highlightAbstract=vaccinat%7Cvaccin%7Cvaccinate)
- [influenza vaccines](https://www.cochranelibrary.com/cdsr/doi/10.1002/14651858.CD008521.pub5/full/ja?highlightAbstract=vaccinat%7Cvaccin%7Cvaccinate)

I found [this article](https://acpinternist.org/weekly/archives/2020/03/03/2.htm?utm_campaign=FY19-20_NEWS_INTERNIST_INTERNATIONAL_030320_EML&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua) further. While this article is limited to the flu vaccine for the elderly, I expect that there will be many more arguments in the future.

I think the intellectual level of the segment of the population that is emotionally averse to vaccines is low. However, I am less confident these days about whether the approved drugs really have clinical significance.